# C# Youtube channel list API is throwing Insufficient Permission [403]

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

The credential json I have received was in this format:

```
{
    "token": "test token",
    "refresh_token": "test refresh",
    "token_uri": "test uri",
    "client_id": "test client id",
    "client_secret": "test client sec",
    "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly"]
}
```

It was throwing the error:

> "Could not cast or convert from System.String to
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleClientSecrets"

I wrapped it inside `{"web":{json}}` and tried, but now it's throwing:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError - Insufficient Permission [403]
>   Errors [Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ]
>   Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]]}

I am using following scopes

`YouTubeAnalyticsService.Scope.YtAnalyticsReadonly`, `YouTubeAnalyticsService.Scope.YtAnalyticsMonetaryReadonly`, `YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl`, `YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube`

while creating credential, but now, it's breaking at .Execute()

```
YouTubeService youtubeService = AnalyticsLoggingHelper.GetYoutubeService(channelinfo);
var channelResourcesList = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
channelResourcesList.Id = channelinfo.ChannelId;
var listResult = channelResourcesList.Execute();
```

Comment: From which youtube video/channel etc you're using this code? The error says you don't have permissions, hence, I doubt you can go futher.